# Get a property value from each array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get the contents of words from each element in the array?

```
[
  {
    words: ['help','good],
    glass: 'empty'
  },
  {
    words: ['low', 'cool'],
    glass: 'full'
  }
]
```

The expected result is:

```
[ 'help, 'good', 'low', 'cool' ]
```

Comment: Could you please provide the expected result? Do you want words in flatten array?

Comment: result should be like this: [ 'help, 'good', 'low', 'cool' ]

Comment: Next time you shouldn't be too generic in the title of your question. I think that's why it has been downvoted. Try to indicate in a few words your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this input:

```js
const value = [
      {
        words: ['help','good'],
        glass: 'empty'
      },
      {
        words: ['low', 'cool'],
        glass: 'full'
      }
    ]

const result = value.flatMap(e => e.words);

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(result)
```

Comment: Nice one-line answer! I didn't think of that!

Comment: I just discovered that one to be honest :-D

Comment: Didn't know it was available directly, thanks I will edit the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
data = [{
    words: ['help', 'good'],
    glass: 'empty'
  },
  {
    words: ['low', 'cool'],
    glass: 'full'
  }
]

words = []

data.forEach(function(dataSet) {
  words.push.apply(words, dataSet.words)
})

console.log(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use reduce if you want

```js
const data = [
  {
    words: ['help','good'],
    glass: 'empty'
  },
  {
    words: ['low', 'cool'],
    glass: 'full'
  }
]

console.log(data.reduce((acc,val) => [...acc, ...val.words],[]))
```